# Updating text on a Panel without making it a separate inner class

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am trying to make a method which when I call from any class updates the string on a specific Panel. descriptionPanel is a static panel and description is a static string which I am defining when I instantiate the class.The class in which I am defining this has a lot of Panels so to specify which panel I have to use, I do descriptionPanel.paintComponent, and this is the panel I would always be updating . 
I know this code won't work, the first mistake being I can't define a method but this is just for giving an idea what I am trying to do.

```
void updateDescriptionPanel(String dataToAppend){

    description = description.concat(dataToAppend);
    descriptionPanel.paintComponent(Graphics g){
            g.drawString(description, 10, 11);
    }
    descriptionPanel.repaint();

}
```

I have tried some things

```
void paintComponent(Graphics g){
g.drawString(description, 10, 11);
}

void updateDescriptionPanel(String dataToAppend){

    description = description.concat(dataToAppend);
    Graphics g=null;
    paintComponent(g);
    descriptionPanel.repaint();

}
```

But here I am unable to tell which panel to update .

[image]

```
public class Application_GUI {

static String description  = "" ;
    static JPanel descriptionPanel;
//other initializations

void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    g.drawString(description, 10, 11);
}
public String[] getRepositoryList(ArrayList<ResourceListObject> imagerepositorylist)
// method which uses another class to get that List
// If I get the list I print a string 
// Connection successful to the description Panel

void updateDescriptionPanel(String dataToAppend){

    description = description.concat(dataToAppend);
    Graphics g=null;
    paintComponent(g);
    descriptionPanel.repaint();
}


final JPanel panel = new JPanel();    

JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
//scrollBar initialization    

descriptionPanel = new JPanel();
final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
//get comboBoxOptions by making a connection and then adding it
//ActionListener inner class for the comboBox
```

This goes on and on 
Pretty much Action Listeners for everything. Some Action Listeners do the things theirselves and some use other classes to do it . So what I want to do is be able to update the descriptionPanel from all action listeners i.e. when an action Listener makes a call to perform certain operation, specifically a swingWorker that is performing a large task the SwingWorker when it completes , it should be able to update the descriptionPanel.

Comment: *"is a static panel and description is a static string"*  That has a distinct 'bad code' smell to it.  The 2 parts that read 'static'.  Using `static` is rarely necessary, and more often an indication of a broken design (pretty much as you seem to already suspect).  That is the first thing I'd look to change.  Further, the way you talk about the panel makes me think it `extends JPanel`.  It should not do that, though GUI designers often tend to (encourage or?) enforce that approach.  Instead you should create an instance of a panel and populate it in a factory method..

Comment: .. (or have the method create the panel).

Comment: But now I look at the code snippets more closely..  Why does the panel use `drawString(..)` instead of a laid out `JLabel`?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Andrew : I was thinking of doing this, extending the JPanel and making it work that ways somehow. But I would have to change a lot of code for that. 
This part of my design has totally broken and this is the last thing I needed to do so I was not thinking of fixing the design, just some workaround.
I think that last part of your comment "populate it in a factory method" looks as if it would suffice . Can you please elaborate or provide some links on how to do it ?
I would post an SSCCE also.

Comment: *"was not thinking of fixing the design, just some workaround"*  I think finding a work-around (that is robust) would be more work than gutting and fixing the design.  Sometimes when I've been experimenting with a new API, I'll write a GUI that gets to the point I think.  OK, now to use the knowledge gained to *design* a program to do this.  At that point almost all the GUI code I wrote is turfed out the window, though I might copy/paste a few lines.